# Changing width size of REDCap text box

Tags: formatting, textbox, redcap

In REDCap, I would like to try and fit a text box and a % sign on the row while it's in a table. Is it possible to shrink the size of the text box in order to fit the % sign to be all on one line? The % sign goes below the text box rather than fit on one line beside of it. [See here for the example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvhMt.png)

I have looked for code online to see if this is possible, but have not found anything on it yet.

thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.